# How to convert a Float to a UInt32

Tags: swift, type-conversion

I'm trying to covert a `Float` to a `UInt32`. This code seems to work:

```
func floatToUInt(float: Float) -> UInt32
{
    return unsafeBitCast(float as Float, to: UInt32.self)
}
```

The compiler complains that 'unsafeBitCast' from 'Float' to 'UInt32' can be replaced with 'bitPattern' property on 'Float'. If I follow the recommendation, it turns it into this:

```
func floatToUInt(float: Float) -> UInt32
{
    return float as Float.bitPattern
}
```

But Xcode then complains with an error:

> Property 'bitPattern' is not a member type of 'Float'

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: It's about converting the representation, not the value, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The auto-correct from Xcode is wrong, `bitPattern` is an instance property, not a type property, so you need to call it on the `float` instance.

```
func floatToUInt(float: Float) -> UInt32 {
  return float.bitPattern
}
```